# how to use the netlogo anonymous -> in this case

Tags: netlogo, anonymous-function

I am having trouble converting an old 5.3.1 task to the an anonymous procedure used in 6.01.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The line I am having trouble with is the following:

```
>let most-efficient? task [first ? = lowest-first]
```

Here it is in the context of the full reporter:

```
> to-report best-route [route-list]  ;; [a list of network sections]                                         
> let lowest-first min map first route-list
> let most-efficient? task [first ? = lowest-first]  
> let best-route first butfirst one-of filter most-efficient? route-list  
> report best-route                  
> end
```

The original code was provided by Seth T.

Regards

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `task` primitive no longer exists. Second, instead of using `?`, you now provide an argument to the primitive using the `->` syntax.

In this case, that looks like:

```
let most-efficient? [route -> first route = lowest-first]
```

Here, we're using an argument `route` in the anonymous procedure. `route` will be used in the same way `?` would've been in the old task syntax.

Note that for two or more arguments, you need to surround them by `[]` to group them together:

```
let add [ [ x y ] -> x + y ]
```

Edit: Forgot to link to the programming guide section on anonymous procedures! It contains the full details:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures